# How to append all SQL results into a single div in HTML instead of creating a new div for each result

Tags: html, sql, database, append

I´m trying to display images from my database. The images are saved on my server and I'm simply fetching the directories from database. Currently, fetching data and appending items to a `div` is simple enough with JavaScript. However, when I try to develop the same function for JavaScript disabled users, I'm not able to figure how to append items to a single `div`. This is my current code, it is working fine

```
<?php 
   $stmt = $DB->("CALL xxx");
   $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
   foreach ($results as $items) {
?>
<div id="images">
    <img src="images/source/<?php echo $items['img_name']?>">
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

However, what I am getting now is every single item result I got would create its own div, like the following

```
<div id="images">
    <img src="images/source/<?php echo $items['img_name1']?>">
</div>
<div id="images">
    <img src="images/source/<?php echo $items['img_name2']?>">
</div><div id="images">
    <img src="images/source/<?php echo $items['img_name3']?>">
</div> etc......
```

But what I would like is the following

```
<div id="images">
    <img src="images/source/<?php echo $items['img_name1']?>">
    <img src="images/source/<?php echo $items['img_name2']?>">
    <img src="images/source/<?php echo $items['img_name3']?>">
    etc...
</div>
```

I hope I am explaining my problem well, thanks in advance for any feedback. Any comments would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just take the div out of the foreach loop.

```
<?php 
   $stmt = $DB->("CALL xxx");
   $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
   $images= "";

   foreach ($results as $items) {
       $images .= '<img src="images/source/'. $items['img_name'].'">';
   }
?>
<div id="images">
    <?php echo $images; ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
   $stmt = $DB->("CALL xxx");
   $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
?>
<div id="images">
<?php
   foreach ($results as $items) {
?>
    <img src="images/source/<?php echo $items['img_name']?>">

<?php } ?>
</div>
```

Having the div outside the loop won't repeat it.

Better:

```
<?php
    $stmt = $DB->("CALL xxx");
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();

    if(!empty(results)):
?>
    <div id="images">
    <?php
        foreach ($results as $items):
    ?>
        <img src="images/source/<?php echo $items['image_name']; ?>" />
    <?php
        endforeach;
    ?>
    </div>
<?php
    endif;
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

To put all of the images into one div, you need to have that div outside of the foreach loop:

```
<?php 
    echo('<div id="images">');
    $stmt = $DB->("CALL xxx");
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    foreach ($results as $items) {
        echo('<img src="images/source/'.$items['img_name'].'">');
    }
    echo('</div>');
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, I wish I could give you the tick